# About a recurrence equation of prime numbers

Tags: prime-numbers

Let $p$ be a prime.

Consider the recurrence equation 
$$s_{n}=(s_{n-1}²-2)(mod(2^{p}-1))$$
where $s₀=4$

My **question** is: 
Can we write this recurrence as follow?
$$s_{n}=(2^{p}-1)q+(s_{n-1}²-2)$$
where $q$ is an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follow by definition of congruency if $x\equiv b(mod\ c)$ then$x=b+c\cdot q$ where q is an integer.Substitute b=$s_{n-1}^2-2$ ,$c=2^p-1$,x=$s_{n}$ .

Comment: @ mcmat23: Is $q$ in the question should be $q_{n}$ since we make the devision of $s_{n}$ and $2^{p}-1$.

Comment: Yes ,q changes for each terms.